# How to get user details and check if user is loggedin in angular2 component

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I have a service for my angularfire2 authentication call auth.service. There I want to use it to check if user is logged in and also to get the logged in user object so I can pass it to the component and use in the templates.

Here is my auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
 user = {};
 isLoggedIn: boolean;
  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
      if(user) {
        // user logged in
        this.user = user;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        console.log(this.user);

      }
      else {
        // user not logged in
        this.user = {};
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    });

   }
```

This works just fine. But I can't seem to get the value of the isLoggedIn key in the component.

I tried calling it in the component as so

```
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
    constructor(private AuthService : AuthService) {

          this.isLoggedIn = this.AuthService.isLoggedIn;
    }
```

My guess is am not doing it the right way. 
How can I get this isLoggedIn value from the auth.service to the component  ? Likewise the better way to get the user object too.

Comment: Are your service and component in the same module? If you are not able to read `AuthSerivce.isLoggedIn` its probably to the hierarchical nature of the Angular DI.

Comment: Yes everything is one module I suppose. I am using Angular-CLi

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that in your another component you call
 this.isLoggedIn = this.AuthService.isLoggedIn in the constructor. The quick fix for this is to make isLoggedIn public in your auth.service and access it from your another component. One example is `<div *ngIf="AuthService.isLoggedIn">`...